# How to access Volume post-processing effects by script in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So, i'm currently working on a 3D game using HDRP and to adjust the brightness of the game I use the component **Color Adjustment** (check out the attached image) and there I change the **Intensity** (the intensity is displayed once clicking the "HDR" option) of the **Color Filter**. So my question is: How do I access this information in a C# script? Is it possible? If it is possible i'd be really happy if you, the person reading this could show me.

Thanks in advance.

[Image of the inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EnSpR.png)

Comment: Have you tried `GetComponent<ColorAdjustments>().ColorFilter`?

Comment: This does not work. Just gives me errors, like "'ColorAdjustments' could not be found".

Answer (score 4):

As per [this answer on the Unity forums](https://forum.unity.com/threads/hdrp-2019-1-how-do-you-change-effects-volume-overrides-through-script.668842/), you can access Volume effects like so:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Rendering;
using UnityEngine.Experimental.Rendering.HDPipeline;
public class AffectDepthOfField : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool spherecast = true;
    public Transform mainCamera;
    RaycastHit hit;

    DepthOfField dofComponent;

    void Start()
    {
        Volume volume = gameObject.GetComponent<Volume>();
        DepthOfField tmp;
        if (volume.profile.TryGet<DepthOfField>(out tmp))
        {
            dofComponent = tmp;
        }
    }
    void Update()
    {
        if (spherecast)
        {
            if (Physics.SphereCast(mainCamera.position, 0.1f, mainCamera.forward, out hit, 10f))
            {
                dofComponent.nearFocusStart = new MinFloatParameter(1f, 0f, true);
                dofComponent.nearFocusEnd = new MinFloatParameter(1f, 0f, true);
                dofComponent.farFocusStart = new MinFloatParameter(1f, 0f, true);
                dofComponent.farFocusEnd = new MinFloatParameter(1f, 0f, true);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I made some progress with this, like referencing Color Adjustments like this: `ColorAdjustments _colorAdjustments = gameObject.GetComponent<ColorAdjustments>();` and then on to change the Color Filter's Intensity by writing `_colorAdjustments.colorFilter` and then I got stuck. Any idea how to change the Intensity of the 'HDR Color' from here?

Answer (score 1):

you could put it in a separate child game object and enable-disable that on will if all you want to do is enable/disable it. (if thats not your intention, just ignore this).

Answer (score 0):

You can drag and drop your Volume Profile into gameVolume and then access the volume properties like this:

```
[SerializeField] private VolumeProfile gameVolume;
private ColorAdjustments colorAdjustments;

private void Awake()
{
    ColorAdjustments cA;
    if (gameVolume.TryGet<ColorAdjustments>(out cA))
    {
        colorAdjustments = cA;
        colorAdjustments.hueShift.overrideState = true;
        colorAdjustments.hueShift.value = 20f;
    }
}
```

If you change the values like this, the change will persist even after you exit play mode.
[Unity Documentation for more info](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.high-definition@10.0/manual/Volumes-API.html)

Answer (score 0):

using UnityEngine.Rendering;

[SerializeField] Volume yourVolume;

Comment: This has nothing to do with OP's question. Please understand the question. Also don't just write the code, provide context & try to be helpful.